# Can I add "Tyranny of King Washington" to Assassin's Creed 3

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I just completed Assassin's Creed 3 (the old one, not the Remastered version), but now I want to play the additional content missions "The Tyranny of King Washington". I can't see where I can buy it from since it is not available in Steam or the UbiStore.

Is there a way to add this additional content?

Answer (score 2):

All 3 parts of the King Washington content are included in the season pass, so if you can find that you'll have everything you want, in addition to:

- [The Hidden Secrets Pack](https://assassinscreed.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hidden_Secrets_Pack)

> It includes three naval memories, one secret location, two outfits, four weapons, two Animi Avatars and two naval-based upgrades.

- [The Battle Hardened Pack](https://assassinscreed.fandom.com/wiki/The_Battle_Hardened_Pack) (multiplayer content)

> The pack includes three new Animi Avatars and simulated maps with the new personas including the Coyote Man, the Governor, and the Highlander.

As of September 9th 2019, the Assassin's Creed III Season Pass is available at the [Humble store](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/assassins-creed-iii-season-pass). Note that it will not activate on Steam, but only on Uplay.

Comment: thanks for the information, but it is €30, which is too much for me. Is there anything else except the 3 parts of Washington ?

Comment: @mihkov Are you asking if the season pass has any content besides the King Washington DLCs, or whether there are other purchasing options?

Comment: I was asking about contents of the season pass, I was not clear enough sorry.

Comment: @mihkov I added that information into the answer.

Answer (score -1):

[https://www.g2a.com/search?query=The Tyranny of King](https://www.g2a.com/search?query=The%20Tyranny%20of%20King) Are they real ? Anyone tried buying codes from this site ? Seems the total price is ~ $28 which is almost the same as Humble store, but if I want to play i need to spend some money.

Comment: After a little read, it's not a good option. More details [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GameDeals/comments/2yhlw4/key_resellers_and_what_they_mean_for_you/)